# Get events emmited from external library on Hardhat tests

Tags: events, solidity, hardhat

I am doing some tests using Hardhat and Chai, and I would like to listen to event that is emitted along the transaction but not declared in the contract (nor the ABI) of the callee contract. EG:
Im calling contract A, which calls library B, which emits an event declared in Library E (not inherited to library A nor contract A):

```
struct Data {
    uint a;
    uint b;
}

contract A {
    Data public data;

    function callToB() external {
        B.changeData(data);
    }
}


library B {
    function changeData(Data storage _data) external {
        _data.a = 10;
        _data.b = 20;
        emit Events.DataChanged();
    }
}

library Events {
    event DataChanged();
}
```

So, how could I listen to the `DataChanged()` event on a hardhat test?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like i found a solution that works:

```
const tx = await this.contractA.callToB
const events: any = (await tx.wait()).events
let eventName = ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.toUtf8Bytes("DataChanged()"))
expect(eventName).to.be.eq(events[0].topics[0])
```

If you had some arguments inside the events, then topics[1], topics[2], etc will have their corresponding value expressed in hex. For example, if the event were to be `DataChanged(changer, time)`, the values could be retrieved:

```
  let [changer] = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(["address"], events[0].topics[1])
  let [time] = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(["uint256"], events[0].topics[2])
```